# regular expression with css properties

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have string with css properties and their values:

```
str = "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, black, white);
       animation-duration: 12s;";
```

and I want to my match returned only properties

```
properties = text.match(/[^;:]*:/g);
```

but it also returns "progid:", how can I avoid it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Depending on that, it might be better to use a CSS parser or just query an elements set style properties..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the beginning of the line or a ";" as well (or possibly a line-break/tab depending on your string formatting):

```
/(^|;)[^:;]*:/
```

You still have to cleanup your results a bit though.

Alternatively, you could split the string on ";" first, then split each bit on ":" and grab the 0th member of each for your properties:

```
var str = "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, black, white);animation-duration: 12s;";

var rules = str.split(";")

var i, l = rules.length;

var properties = [];

for( i = 0; i < l; i++ ){
    properties.push( rules[ i ].split(":")[0] ); //dangerous if you're not sure you'll always have a result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
properties = text.match(/^[^;:]*:/g);
```

EDIT:
Here is a better solution provided there is always a space between property and value:

```
properties = text.match(/[^ ;:]+(?=: )/g)
```

Comment: That only works if each line has an actual line return at it's end.  Not certain that was the case since there is no "\" preceding the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the empty rule when you split on a semi that ends the string,

split on semis with content following them;

```
var rules= str.split(/;(?=\S+)/);

for(var i= 0, L= rules.length; i<L; i++){
    rules[i]= rules[i].split(':')[0];   
}

/* 
alert(rules)>>(Array)
filter, background, animation-duration
*/
```